# Reference needed for Determinant of convex combination of two matrices as a function

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

What can one say about the function $(t,A,B) \mapsto \det(tA + (1-t)B)$, with $t \in [0,1]$, $A$, $B$ square matrices, in my case, say, permutational matrices? Where such a function shows up? Hoping for some references.

Comment: I am not sure that this is your case, but still if $A,B$ are symmetric and positive definite matrices then the function $t\mapsto \log\det(tA+(1-t)B)$ is concave on the segment $[0,1]$. In other words the function $A\mapsto \log\det A$ is concave on the cone of positive definite matrices. This is used in the theory of Monge-Ampere equations.

Comment: If $B$ is invertible, then $\mathrm{det}(tA+(1-t)B)=\mathrm{det}(B)\mathrm{det}(tAB^{-1}+(1-t)I)$ which can be expressed in terms of the characteristic polynomial for $AB^{-1}$.

Comment: thank you sva and Oscar. Both comments are very useful.

Comment: If permutational matrices we can interpret the matrix $tA+(1-t)B$ as a continuum of markov chains. In the extreme cases of $t=0$ or $t=1$ they will be deterministic ( 100% probability for each non-zero probability ) and we will be sure of row and column sum equal to 1 will be preserved for all other t in the interval.

Comment: Thank you mathreadler. Indeed in permutational case determinant of stochastic matrix is some wonderful function.  Here is a discussion. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932548/interpretation-for-the-determinant-of-a-stochastic-matrix

Comment: If we rewrite to have symmetry $(t-1)A + (t+1)B$, $t\in[-1,1]$ and plot the determinant it gets suspiciously close to some monomials $t^n$. I don't quite see the connection between $n$ and matrix side, but seems to be related.